# Reasonable use of goroutines in Go programs

Tags: go, goroutine

My program has a long running task. I have a list `jdIdList` that is too big - up to `1000000` items, so the code below doesn't work. Is there a way to improve the code with better use of goroutines?

It seems I have too many goroutines running which makes my code fail to run.

What is a reasonable number of goroutines to have running?

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(len(jdIdList))
c := make(chan string)

// just think jdIdList as [0...1000000]
for _, jdId := range jdIdList {
    go func(jdId string) {
        defer wg.Done()
        for _, itemId := range itemIdList {
            // following code is doing some computation which consumes much time(you can just replace them with time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
            cvVec, ok := cvVecMap[itemId]
            if !ok {
                continue
            }
            jdVec, ok := jdVecMap[jdId]
            if !ok {
                continue
            }
            // long time compute
            _ = 0.3*computeDist(jdVec.JdPosVec, cvVec.CvPosVec) + 0.7*computeDist(jdVec.JdDescVec, cvVec.CvDescVec)
        }
        c <- fmt.Sprintf("done %s", jdId)
    }(jdId)

}

go func() {
    for resp := range c {
        fmt.Println(resp)
    }
}()
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @FilipHaglund I change my question

Comment: I'm still having a hard time figuring out what you are actually trying to ask. You are saying that your problem is that `jdIdList`is too big, but that's not your actual problem, right? What's happening, and what do you want to happen?

Comment: @FilipHaglund about this time?

Comment: if you want to use less gorouting,  select a chan in fixed-number(like cpu num?) goroutine, and send the task from main goroutine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're running too many things concurrently, making your computer run out of memory.

Here's a version of your code that uses a limited number of worker goroutines instead of a million goroutines as in your example. Since only a few goroutines run at once, they have much more memory available each before the system starts to swap. Make sure the memory each small computation requires times the number of concurrent goroutines is less than the memory you have in your system, so if the code inside `for jdId := range work` loop requires less than 1GB memory, and you have 4 cores and at least 4 GB of RAM, setting `clvl` to `4` should work fine.

I also removed the waitgroups. The code is still correct, but only uses channels for synchronization. A for range loop over a channel reads from that channel until it is closed. This is how we tell the worker threads when we are done.

https://play.golang.org/p/Sy3i77TJjA

```
runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU()) // not needed on go 1.5 or later
c := make(chan string)
work := make(chan int, 1) // increasing 1 to a higher number will probably increase performance
clvl := 4 // runtime.NumCPU() // simulating having 4 cores, use NumCPU otherwise
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(clvl)
for i := 0; i < clvl; i++ {
    go func(i int) {
        for jdId := range work {
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 100)
            c <- fmt.Sprintf("done %d", jdId)
        }
        wg.Done()
    }(i)
}

// give workers something to do
go func() { 
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        work <- i
    }

    close(work)
}()

// close output channel when all workers are done
go func() { 
    wg.Wait()
    close(c)
}()

count := 0
for resp := range c {
    fmt.Println(resp, count)
    count += 1
}
```

which generated this output on go playground, while simulating four cpu cores.

```
done 1 0
done 0 1
done 3 2
done 2 3
done 5 4
done 4 5
done 7 6
done 6 7
done 9 8
done 8 9
```

Notice how the ordering is not guaranteed. The `jdId` variable holds the value you want. You should always test your concurrent programs using the [go race detector](https://blog.golang.org/race-detector).

Also note that if you are using go 1.4 or earlier and haven't set the GOMAXPROCS environment variable to the number of cores, you should do that, or add `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())` to the beginning of your program.

Comment: you can try this, your code make `dead lock`, http://play.golang.org/p/1CjQrnyQzQ

Comment: I missed that deadlock. It's good though, since it means that the computation actually finished; the output you got is all the output. 

If we add a waitgroup with `clvl` elements, remove on each time a worker exits and break out of the final print loop when that waitgroup is done, we won't deadlock.

Comment: Your version contains a race condition that is unlikely to be noticed unless run on more than one cpu core. Using a waitgroup fixes this. I've updated the answer with a correct solution.

Comment: I have test your code, it runs well, but I still can not understand what do you mean  `race condition` with my code?

Comment: As soon as the first goroutine finished its work, it closed the output channel. This ment that the jobs that the other goroutines were doing was never returned. For 4 goroutines, this ment up to 3 responses were lost. If you have any more follow-up questions, post them as a new question on this site.